# What is known about the "moduli space of morphisms" $X \to Y$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ and $Y$ be projective varieties.  I am assuming that there is some construction of a "moduli space" parametrizing the morphisms $X \to Y$. For instance, if one identifies such morphisms with their graphs in $X \times Y$, one can at least hope that these graphs would correspond to a locally closed subscheme of the Chow or Hilbert schemes for $X \times Y$, although this may not be the best way to construct such a space.  In the case of $X = Y = \mathbb{P}^n$, this space should probably be <strike>a disjoint union of $PGL_n$ with $\mathbb{P}^n$</strike> [**Edit:**This is not correct; I know a theorem that the image must be either a point or all $\mathbb{P}^n$, but grossly misapplied it by neglecting maps of degree > 1].  (I am requiring the varieties to be projective because, for instance, if $Y$ is the affine line, then the morphisms $X$ to $Y$ would naturally correspond to the global sections of $X$, which for general $X$ is too big to fit in one nice scheme, being infinite-dimensional.  Although I suppose it might work if we confined ourselves to e.g. morphisms of a fixed degree, and we are already doing something of this sort in looking at Chow or Hilbert schemes, so perhaps my concern here is needless.)

Is there a standard space that represents these morphisms, and if so, what is known about it?  Is there a good reference for this?

Comment: See the book by Koll\'ar, "Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties", Chapter 1.

Comment: Also, to address your example when $n = 1$, degree $d > 0$ maps from P^1 to P^1 may be identified with two degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials in two variables with no common factor (up to a total scaling).  So the Hom scheme in this case is much bigger than you suggest!

Comment: mdeland: Thanks for the correction. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is called the Hom scheme, and I think it's defined in Grothendieck's [Bourbaki 221 paper](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SB_1960-1961__6__249_0), where he constructs the Hilbert and Quot schemes.  For any $S$-schemes $X$ and $Y$, $\underline{Hom}_S(X,Y)$ assigns to any $S$-scheme $T$ the set $Hom_T(X_T,Y_T)$.  Osserman has a quick overview of the constructions, which you can find with Google.  Olsson's paper "Hom stacks and restriction of scalars" is one possible reference that covers a more general setting.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the most important step in looking something up is knowing what it is called.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good non-stacky intro to this in the first chapter of [Rational curves on algebraic varieties](http://books.google.com/books?id=oqW3GabJLjgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=rational+curves+on+algebraic+varieties&source=bl&ots=_9g9ialfeP&sig=UtO_riBs-jfgZnC_f3Pj2Rlm_tA&hl=en&ei=L_DSTK7rK4zWtQO2obCkDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) by János Kollár. You can also find some very nice applications there, such as Mori's *Bend & Break*.